# How can I use Python to receive input from HTML in my Chrome extension?

Tags: python, html

In my extension, I have an input box, and a button. What I would like is for text to be submitted, and when the button is clicked, a summary to be generated.

This is my Python and HTML code (it's very simple).
Python Code:

```
import gensim
from gensim.summarization import summarize

def summary(original_text):
    return summarize(original_text)
```

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input placeholder="Paste your text here!"> </input>
    <button type="button" id='button_summarize'> Summarize! </button>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use flask but I realised it would not work since I'm trying to create an extension. Is there any way I'd get the Python to communicate with my HTML? Sample code would be helpful as I'm a bit new to this (hopefully it isn't too cumbersome given the simplicity of the task).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
no there isn't a way you should be using javascript.

Long answer (for die hard pythonists):
use [brython](https://brython.info/) or something similar.

you can add an event listener to the button in brython with

```py
document['button_summarize'].bind('click',function)
```

Comment: How would the Javascript and Python communicate with each other?

Comment: brython handles that you can just write python not javascript

Comment: Can I use gensim with Brython? I'm getting some errors here